# Pull request button missing

Tags: git, github, pull-request

So, I'm practicing git on my computer on a single repo with two different users as collaborators.

**User1**

- created a repo, invited another user to collaborate.
- pushed a simple `index.html` file to the remote master.
- checked out a branch `input1` from master, pushed to the local branch, send pull request, and merged to the remote master.

**User2**

- checkout to another branch `input2`, take a pull by `git pull origin master`, get files `index.html` and `input1.html` in my local.
- pushed changes to local branch.
- However, now there's no `Compare and pull request button` on my repo i.e., User 2 account, but i can see the button on User1 github account. Also the line-`Your recently pushed branches:` is only visible on User1 account.

Why is this happening?

Note: It is the same public repo where User1 and User2 are working.

Comment: How are you pushing?  SSH or HTTPS?

Comment: using HTTPS....

Comment: Are you prompted for credentials each time?  If so, what credentials are you providing in each case?

Comment: I have cloned the repository on two places. One's on desktop and other is on documents. I've given different username and email. User1 has different git config name and email, User2 has different. I can also see who's pushed what in the repo itself.

Comment: Ummm no, not every time. I'm using git bash.

Comment: Hey, I just checked User2 profile on github and there's no commit there. It's empty. No contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push to a repository, the credentials used don't have anything to do with the `user.name` and `user.email` settings.  These settings are used to write the author and committer information into commits, but are not used in any way for authentication.

If you're not being prompted for credentials, then the likely issue is that you have credentials saved in your credential manager and those credentials (for User1) are being sent as authentication.  So while your commits will look like they were created by User2, they were actually pushed by User1.

Note that it's intentional that you can push commits created by other people, since many workflows use patches who are authored by one person and committed by another.  This is used by Git and the Linux kernel, for example.

The easiest way to ensure you use the correct account is to always put the username in the URL, like so: `https://bk2204@github.com/git/git.git`.  This ensures that your credential manager gets a hint about what username to use and allows you to use multiple accounts if you want.

If you're not sure what URL you have, you can use `git remote -v` to see them and `git remote set-url origin URL` to set the remote of `origin` to `URL`.

Note that contributions only show up when they've merged into the main branch, so if the commits are not in `master` (or your code's equivalent), then they won't be counted as contributions.